# Is it possible to create FB Apps with script?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I'm building a product that involves clients adding their FB app data into my product's dashboard.

In this case each client would have to go to developers.facebook.com/apps and create an app first.

I would want to have a button which says "Create App" in my website that when clicked, would create the app instantly for the client.

So is it possible to create a FB App from my website (with script, not manually) ??

Thanks in advance,
Altin.

Answer (score 1):

It was possible couple of years ago, and now it's been removed.

Comment: Ahhh, I remember I have seen some product months ago that created apps the way I need here but I couldn't find anything from google search. That's why I was in doubt. Thanks for the answer though, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I’d think about the question, “does every client really need their *own* app?”

Maybe it’d also be possible to have all of the stuff you’re planning to do (no details on that) under *one* app, and have it decide on what data to show based on the fact which client’s Facebook page it gets added to (if it’ll run as page tab app), or by some additional parameter passed to it when calling it. You could f.e. example automatically redirect to a sub-folder on your webspace based on this criteria, that displays individual pages for that client.

If that’s not an option, then yes, your clients will have to set up the *basic* app themselves (and therefor they’ll need a *verified* account) – and afterwards tell app id and secret to you. Many of the “advanced” app settings can then be set by you via script – look at what properties are marked as *“(Editable via API)”* here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

(Although some of the basic settings, like category, description, logo etc. will still have to be set by your client themselves. But other, more “technical” stuff, that the client maybe doesn’t know about and doesn’t even want to be bothered with, like canvas/page tab URLs etc. can be set by you. I’d say that’s as good a compromise as you can get for such a scenario.)

Comment: hi CBroe,

the thing is that this app/product will be for internet marketers and because of that, it may be possible that some clients will miss-use it and spam and get reported. So I don't wanna take the risk of the main app getting blocked if one or more clients get reported. Because of the nature of this product, if I would use one app and pass url parameters to identify users, there is a high risk of the main app to get reported or blocked and that would put the entire user-network links down, making it useless and not repairable.

thanks for your reply however, appreciate it :)

Comment: OK, that’s understandable reasoning :-)

Comment: by the way after some research I think I found a way to create apps programmatically by using this:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/create_app.php?api_key=MAIN_APP_API_KEY&name=NEW_APP_NAME

Now I can create apps and then edit the newly created app's settings via FB API :)

So now I have to consider the first reply by Zerkms as wrong..

Comment: OK, if that (still?) works, fine. But I guess there’s still no way to set the app properties like description, category etc. that are not marked editable via API in the docs …? If so, then without user interaction you’ll end up with “half-setup” apps. I mean, the important stuff for it to work may be there (URLs, privacy policy, etc.) – but without description, icon etc. the user experience may lack a little bit …

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right :) I think i must go with creating the app programmatically, then redirecting the user to the app settings page to complete the information manually...